# Android - Launch service at Boot but without Boot Completed Permission

Tags: android, permissions, alarmmanager, boot

I'm developing an app that needs to keep running a background service. That's why I start that service on the onCreate method of the Main Activity.

But what I'd like to do is that service be always running, even if I didn't start the app after a device restart. I know there's a permission that I could use that is called "ON BOOT COMPLETED". i could capture that Broadcast, I know.

But I don't want to ask user for that permission.

What should I do? The app Fucking Weather has a Service always running and in its Manifest it doesn't declare the "ON BOOT COMPLETED" permission. How do they do that trick? That's what I need.

I tried an AlarmManager that executes every X seconds, but it won't start until the app is not open.

Comment: They may be listening for another broadcast that is sent periodically from the system, but really this is what the boot receiver is for. Why are you against using it?

Comment: It feels like a strange permission for me. I'd like to get the silent approach

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW and standard broadcast actions. One of those may work but you should really be receiving boot completed since that's when you want to start.

Comment: Thanks. I like your proposal of looking for other broadcasts. Thanks. Maybe I should take a look to the fw's manifest.

Comment: I used Application class with shutdown receiver to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29594003/2919924

Comment: @ahmedibrahim085 I liked your proposal but I saw that also I need the boot completed permission

Comment: @joaquin You can remove it(boot completed permission ) and remove the boot broadcast class. I put them in the project just for demonstration. I thought it will be nicer if some run the program and saw the logs coming from both the Application class and the boot class as a prove that my aproach works. Then S/he can remove them later. try doing so , and tell me